# NSOutlineView + Core Data without using NSTreeController

Tags: cocoa

I would like to use NSOutlineView + Core Data(without NSTreeController) to create a software. the Core Data act as the dataSource. But the software often crash when I click discourse triangle. (I can fetch the correct data from Core Data)

Do I have to use NSTreeController?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

why do you not want to use a tree controller, just don't want to learn how to use it?

basically yes you can, you just have to implement the data source and delegate methods, but you won't be able to use bindings.

Comment: For exercise and familiar with NSOutlineView and Core Data operations.

Comment: basically your model design should be just as if you were using binding, it should be kvc compliant for (the key name isn't especially important but you want to cover your relationships) children, node, parent etc.